# How to implement a callback function or handler option

Tags: javascript

I'm using waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#shortcuts-examples) and greensock (http://www.greensock.com/) to trigger the movement of certain elements when a user is at different levels of a parralax page.

```
function mover(speed, targetx, targety) {
    TweenMax.to($(".four"), speed, {x:targetx, y:targety});
    console.log("waypoint reached");
    alert("Down")
}
```

is called by:

```
$(".three").waypoint(mover($(".four"), 1, 32, 32));
```

However, the javascript console keeps giving me this message (despite everything working perfectly, visually)

```
Uncaught Error: jQuery Waypoints needs a callback function or handler option.   jquery.js:4
x.extend.error jquery.js:4
$.fn.(anonymous function) waypoints.js:360
(anonymous function) scroll.js:15
c jquery.js:4
p.fireWith jquery.js:4
x.extend.ready jquery.js:4
q
```

I've tried returning "true" but the error doesn't go away. How can I integrate a callback function or handler option into my function?

Answer (score 0):

Waypoints throws an error if you [invoke it without a callback or parameter](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started). It's whole purpose in life is to do something when you scroll up or down to an element.

If your code is doing what you need it to do, maybe you don't need waypoints at all.

Can you post the compete code, or at least a full example with the call to waypoints?

Answer (score 0):

As mostly_perl_guy said, you need to define a callback function when you call `waypoint()` :

http://jsfiddle.net/FPzUy/1/

```
$(function() {

            // this works
    $('#w').waypoint(function() {
        console.log('hello');
    });

            // this fails
    $('#w2').waypoint();

});
```